# Passay generate password without repeating characters

Tags: java, passwords

Currently, I'm using passay to generate a random password.

```
new PasswordGenerator().generatePassword(8,
  Arrays.asList(
  new CharacterRule( EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase, 2 ),
  new CharacterRule( EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase, 2 ),
  new CharacterRule( EnglishCharacterData.Digit, 2 ),
  new CharacterRule( EnglishCharacterData.Special, 2 ) ) );
```

May I know how to generate random password without repeating any characters?

```
Password: abcxyz12 //valid

Password: abcxyzpa // invalid because a is repeating
```

I am using passay to generate password

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
  <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Use if statements to check if first one is equal to second, and third, and vice versa. If you calculate, you will have 3+2+1 if statements, which is 6 if statements. This is not the best way to do it, but it still works!!!

Comment: You do realize that preventing character repeats ***decreases*** entropy and security, right?

Comment: What is wrong with just sticking with your current library?  I mean, you are basically telling us that you want to redo work already done by something else.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes you are correct. But the application for which I am generating password has this rule. The rule says "same character may occur 2 times within a password". So was wondering how to achieve this

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just need a way to restrict generated password to have unique characters

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/vt-middleware/passay/blob/master/src/main/java/org/passay/PasswordGenerator.java#L65), you can specify minimum number of a particular character, but not maximum.

So I think the easiest way would be to generate a large password using this library, and then remove repeating characters and then limit to the length you want:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
generatePassword.chars()
        .distinct()
        .limit(8)
        .forEach(c -> sb.append((char) c));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This might be a bit inefficient, so if performance is critical, I would suggest writing your own generator (I tried it just now, it's not difficult to create one). You can find the set of characters in [org.passay.EnglishCharacterData](https://github.com/vt-middleware/passay/blob/master/src/main/java/org/passay/EnglishCharacterData.java).

Comment: Your own generator then.